# Why would a god create demons that try to destroy everything he created?

Tags: creature-design, gods

There is a entity, name him *God*, that created the universe. God created humans, minor gods (Zeus, Odin, Loki, Et cetera). And demons. Each of these things live in their own world. However Demons and Gods can't enter each others world. Yet they both can enter the human world. The demons hate everything God created and try to destroy it. They even want to destroy God.

Why would God create such beings and allow them to exist?

(BTW: Balance is not an option, demons constantly try to break this balance.)
(PS: I refer to him as *God*, but he is not the christian god)

Comment: "The demons hate everything God created and try to destroy it" - did God bestow this hatred and purpose upon them when He created them, or did they develop it of their own free will?

Comment: He made them that way. He did it all on purpose.

Comment: Eternity is boring. Why getting a PS4 when you can create good, evil and enjoy their fight?

Comment: okay I undo it.

Comment: Who's assumed that he's the Christian deity?

Comment: @RonJohn Someone posted a (now-deleted) answer that seemed to be running off that assumption.

Comment: God works in mysterious ways. The creature cannot comprehend the Creator. All that happens happens in order to further God's plan. And so on and so forth.

Comment: @F1Krazy that was my post, and in no was assumed a Christian deity.  The fact is, though, that Christians **have** been asking this question for a **long** time, and answers to those questions would be helpful to OP.

Answer (score 3):

So they are actually teenagers in their emo phase eating Aderall and cutting themselves? Because they are creations of god and try to destroy everything he created and the closest thing are them.  After all, you cannot spell "demon" without an "EMO".

The first thing is that god created demons, but NOT the hate in them. The hate is coming from within (that's why Satan helps you to be a better blues player; the blues was in you all along).

So, like the bible says, the god created an angel, who later turned into a demon because of his own needs, urges and wants.

NOW, the second part of question, why god would allow such entity to exist? God can be indifferent, this was god's plan along, his complex motives, god likes to have challenge (after eons he likes to have a fight or two).

Answer (score 1):

#### Balance is not an option, yet balance is the only option

All things that are created must ultimately be destroyed. While the demons do their best to destroy everything and undo the balance, ultimately they cannot as they were not granted sufficient power.

#### Loki is a special case

Loki is not a spirit of destruction, he's a spirit of chaos. Sometimes a friend, sometimes an enemy, always bringing change. Loki stops you getting stuck in a rut and slowly fading away.

Answer (score 0):

The old [problem of evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil): why would an all-powerful, all-loving god create pain and suffering. Maybe pain and suffering and destruction are a necessary part of the universe.  Since God is all-loving, she can’t create them directly so, instead, she has created demons that have free will and an evil soul.  That way they can make the choice to be destructive and to take the sin on themselves.

Answer (score 0):

#### Boredom

Your *God* was bored. Simple as that. He wanted to do *something* so he started to create things that could oppose him and be a challenge for him. He just wants to see what they are doing and how they are trying to oppose him. It's a sort of reality-TV show for him that helps him through eternity.

Humans, minor gods, demons, ... all of them are just toys.

Toys that God will at some point don't want anymore because they bore him - and then he will destroy all of them and create something new. Something entertaining. Something that is more of a challenge. Or less. Depending on his mood for the current billion years or so.

Eternity is a looooooong time and spending it alone without any action it extremely boooooooring.